# L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn' COMPOisson

Tags: r, regression, poisson

I want to fit `COMPoisson` regression and showed this error:

> L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

I have 115 participant with two independent variable(ADT, HV) & dependent variable(Cr.fatal).

syntax:

```
library(COMpoissonReg)

comp3<-glm.cmp(CR.fatal ~ADT+HV,data = cdata)
```

output:

> Error in optim(par.init, loglik, method = optim.method, control = optim.control,  :
> L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks a lot , it`s simple. we want to fit a Com-poisson regression in package COMpoissonReg but R Showed this error.

Comment: In fact, we have to add a function Optim to codes but where to write?

Comment: Hi,  it would be good if you could edit your question with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)